# Swagger yaml not cooperating

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi

I am almost done with my Swagger yaml file but there is a particular piece that I cannot seem to write out correctly:

You see where it says `invitationCompletedOn` and afterwards I need to add `createdOn` and `completedOn`:

[image]

When I add `createdOn` like so:

```
invitationCompletedOn:
  type: string
  example: 2021-09-22T08:27:49.622Z
createdOn:
  type: string
  example: 2021-09-22T08:27:49.622Z
```

But that breaks the output. Here is the entire yaml file:

```
/**
* @openapi
* /api/v2/organizations/:organizationId/invitations:
*   get:
*     description: Get a list of Data Access Object invitations.
*     responses:
*       200:
*         description: Get a list of Data Access Object invitations.
*         content:
*           application/json:
*             schema:
*               type: object
*               properties:
*                 data:
*                   type: array
*                   items:
*                     type: object
*                     properties:
*                       _type:
*                         type: string
*                         description: Data Transfer Object of new invitation.
*                         example: ViewInvitationDto
*                       email:
*                         type: string
*                         description: Invitation email.
*                         example: dolittle@qa.co
*                       pui:
*                         type: string
*                         description: The patients user id.
*                         example: spyrt_p10102acc
*                       groupId:
*                         type: string
*                         description: The organizations identification.
*                         example: poi_5002
*                       roleDescription:
*                         type: string
*                         description: The role of the organization.
*                         example: admin
*                       viewHealthWorkerDto:
*                         type: object
*                         properties:
*                           _type:
*                             type: string
*                             description: Data Access Object for HealthWorker
*                             example: ViewHealthWorkerDto
*                           _id:
*                             type: string
*                             description: Identification for Healthworker
*                             example: 613ef0964b525196cf8599bf
*                           assignedRoleCode:
*                             type: string
*                             description: Assigned code role for organizations and healthworkers.
*                             example: armada.organization.doctor
*                           pui:
*                             type: string
*                             description: Assigned code role for organizations and healthworkers.
*                             example: spyrt_p10102acc
*                           firstName:
*                             type: string
*                             description: The first name of the healthworker.
*                             example: John
*                           lastName:
*                             type: string
*                             description: The last name of the healthworker.
*                             example: Dolittle
*                           healthWorkerTags:
*                               example:
*                                 - key: migratedOn
*                                   value: 2021-11-19T00:00:43.722Z
*                                 - key: exporterVersion
*                                   value: 2
*                                 - key: _oldAccountId
*                                   value: 10102
*                                 - key: _oldPatientIds
*                                   value: 10729
*                           schemaVersion:
*                             type: string
*                             example: 1
*                           createdOn:
*                             type: string
*                             example: 2020-05-08T07:43:43.000Z
*                           updatedOn:
*                             type: string
*                             example: 2020-05-08T07:43:43.000Z
*                           roleDescription:
*                             type: string
*                             example: admin
*                           email:
*                             type: string
*                             example: dolitle@qa.co
*                           userTags:
*                               example:
*                                 - key: migratedOn
*                                   value: 2021-11-19T00:00:43.722Z
*                                 - key: exporterVersion
*                                   value: 2
*                                 - key: _oldAccountId
*                                   value: 10102
*                                 - key: _oldPatientIds
*                                   value: 10729
*                           invitationCompletedOn:
*                             type: string
*                             example: 2021-09-22T08:27:49.622Z
*
*
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createdOn` and `completedOn` should probably be sibling properties of `viewHealthWorkerDto` rather than of `invitationCompletedOn`. Try this:

```
*                       viewHealthWorkerDto:
*                         type: object
*                         properties:
*                           ...
*                       createdOn:
*                         type: string
*                         example: 2021-09-22T08:27:49.622Z
*                       completedOn:
*                         type: string
*                         example: 2021-09-22T08:27:49.622Z
```

Also, I see that you've defined an example value for `userTags` but no actual schema. From your screenshot, it looks like `userTags` (and similar arrays of key-value objects) can be properly defined like so:

```
*                           userTags:
*                               type: array
*                               items:
*                                 type: object
*                                 properties:
*                                   key:
*                                     type: string
*                                   value:
*                                     type: string
*                               example:
*                                 - key: migratedOn
*                                   value: 2021-11-19T00:00:43.722Z
*                                 - ...
```